# sqlite using blob for epoch datetime

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to decide what is the best way to store a datetime in sqlite. The date will be in epoch.
[I've been reading on wiki about the 2038 problem (it's very much like the year 2000 problem).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) Taking this into account with what I've been reading on tutorialspoint:

From https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm

Tutorialspoint suggests using the below data types form datetime.

> SQLite does not have a separate storage class for storing dates and/or times, but SQLite is capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL or INTEGER values.

But when I looked at the type descriptions, BLOB didn't have a size limit and represents the data as it is inserted into the database.

> BLOB The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.
>
> INTEGER The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

I saw on tutorials point that they suggest using sqlite type INTEGER for datetime. But taken with 2038 problem, I'm thinking that using BLOB is a better choice if I'm focusing on future proofing because BLOB does not have a dependence on a specific number of bytes like INTEGER does depend.

I'm new to database design, so I'm wondering what's best to do?

Comment: Use integer, not blob, for storing integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INTEGER as it says can be up to **8** bytes i.e. a **64 bit signed integer**. Your issue is not SQLite being able to store values not subject to the 2038 issue with 32 bits. Your issue will be in retrieving a time from something that is not subject to the issue, that is unless you are trying to protect against the year 292,277,026,596 problem.

There is no need to use a BLOB and the added complexity and additional processing of converting between a BLOB and the time.

It may even be that you can use SQLite itself to retrieve suitable values, if you wanted to store the current time or a time based upon the current time aka **now**.

Perhaps consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS timevalues;
/* Create the table with 1 column with a weird type and a default value as now (seconds since Jan 1st 1970)*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timevalues (dt typedoesnotmatterthtamuch DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now')));
/* INSERT 2 rows with dates of 1000 years from now */
INSERT INTO timevalues  VALUES 
    (strftime('%s','now','+1000 years')), 
    ((julianday('now','+1000 years') - 2440587.5)*86400.0);
/* INSERT a row using the DEFAULT */ 
INSERT INTO timevalues (rowid) /* specify the rowid column so there is no need to supply value for the dt column */
    VALUES ((SELECT count() FROM timevalues)+1 /* get the highest rowid + 1 */);
/* Retrieve the data rowid, the value as stored in the dt column and the dt column converted to a user friendly format */ 
SELECT rowid,*, datetime(dt,'unixepoch') AS userfriendly FROM timevalues;
/* Cleanup the Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS timevalues;
```

Which results in :-

[image]

- You would probably want to have a read of [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) e.g. for **strftime**, **julianday** and **now**
- rowid is a special normally hidden column that exists for all table unless it is WITHOUT ROWID table. It wouldn't typically be used, or if so aliased by using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

  - see [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) to find out about **rowid** and alias thereof and why not to use AUTOINCREMENT.
- a column type of **typedoesnotmatterthtamuch** see [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) as to why this can be.